# How to make view controller expand to fit layout on smaller screens?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints

I am working on adding constraints to my view. I have everything perfectly laid out for the iPhone X and it looks great, but I would like my view to expand/scroll to accommodate smaller screens sizes. How can I transform my current view to scroll only if the screen size is not as tall as the iPhone X? ideally with as little reconfiguring as possible.

Comment: just put it in scroll view

Comment: @DevilDecoder how do I make it so the view doesn't scroll at all on the iPhone X family?

Comment: scroll view automatically adjust it if your content is grater than scroll view size only than it will scroll otherwise is will not

Answer (score 0):

I follow this approach.

1. Put all your UI components inside a UIView say it ContainerView.
2. Now put ContainerView inside a UIScrollView.
3. Now select ContainerView, add constraints to make width and height equal as of scroll view.
4. Add a constraint of height on ContainerView. Set its relation as "Greater Than or Equal". Set constant value equal to the height which you want.
5. Set priority of equal height constraint to High.

[image]